# eas local build error: firebase-admin/app could not be found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, expo, firebase-admin, react-native-firebase

I am building an Expo app using React Native Firebase and Cloud Functions, the Firebase Deploy succeeds but fails the build `EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_SKIP_CLEANUP=1 eas build -p ios --local` at the Run Fastlane step, with the following error in the Xcode logs:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module firebase-admin/app from /private/var/folders/vq/76jb0whj7y9_1b2pmhxflkrh0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/2bde205e-f2d2-4122-81ca-f597c8744b05/build/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/app.js: firebase-admin/app could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
```

What should I do? And why is functions/node_modules not referenced?

My functions/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.database();

exports.functionName = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  //
})
```

Since functions/node_modules was not referenced, firebase-functions and firebase-admin were also installed in the project root.